# Object Oriented Programming - Class & Subclass Structure

Tags: class, subclass

I've recently started to learn programming and below is the structure I have set up. I was told that if the subclasses are using the same attribute, then I should not be making separate classes. So my question is whether the approach I have is bad and if so why?

My thinking was that for each new object that was made, I would not need to specify a price everytime.
Any insight, articles or other resources would be great.
Thanks in advance

```
abstract ticket class{
seatNumber;
}

childTicket{
price = 10;
}

adultTicket{
price = 20;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As one fellow beginner to another, here's what helped me the most towards understanding classes, subclasses and inheritance:

1. The MSDN library. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228387(v=vs.90).aspx - All you can read.
2. This fellow: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EiKwFK4ddMk - Brief and to the point.

A simple example of Inheritance, which will spare you the typing of repeated code would be:

```
class Accounts
{
    public string clientName;
    public double accountBalance;
    public double interestRate;
    public bool canDeposit = true;
}


 class DepositAccounts : Accounts  
 {            

 }
```

Where DepositAccounts has all the properties of the class account. I believe that will be of use when it comes to setting the price on each of your different types of tickets.

What are your sources? Are you using any textbooks at this point? 
If not, I strongly recommend "Fundamentals of computer programming with C#" by Nakov & Co., which can be found online.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Even if these could be great points for the answer, try to avoid link-only answers, in case these links rot. Instead, try to provide some points from these links in your own answer